# Android MultiScreen Intent Issue

Tags: android, android-intent

I devised some activities with its relationships between each other after I pass any acttivity from Main Actvity. But I couldn't succeed to pass another activity from any activity.

Here is the code below.

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_istanbul);

        TextView attractivePlaces = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_category_attractive_places);

        attractivePlaces.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,B.class);  // Here the issue is.
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });


    }
}
```

How can I solve the problem.

Comment: What does the error log say ?

Comment: Is the toast appearing?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing View.OnClickListener() to TextView.OnClickListener()
final code would be like this:

```
public class A extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_istanbul);

    TextView attractivePlaces = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.a_category_attractive_places);

    attractivePlaces.setOnClickListener(new TextView.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"A",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(A.this,B.class);  // Here the issue is.
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
}
```

Maybe this will help.